# Trying to print an error message

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print an error message appear on the page error message is:

> ERROR
>   Your request has not been successful. You need to contact Customer Care to arrange a replacement.

Now in above error message "contact customer care" is a link which redirects to another page.

I have tried below ways to get the text:

```
//  WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'contact Customer Care')]"));
or
//  WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Your request has not been successful. You need to')]"));
or
//  WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/app/contact']"));
or
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SubmitFormError']"));

System.out.println(text.getText());
```

Nothing is working. It is not printing anything.

The code is:

```html
<div id="SubmitFormError" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<p></p>
<p id="yui_3_17_2_1_1523943995346_146">Your request has not been successful. You need to
 <a href="/app/contact" class="link-dark-bold" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1523943995346_145">contact Customer Care</a> to arrange a replacement.
</p>
<p></p>

</div>
```

Comment: You want to print the content of your link?

Comment: My wild guess is that you have to access to the the div with id "yui_3_17_2_1_1523943995346_146", because technically there is no text in the div "SubmitFormError

Comment: @swiggels, yes I want to print that Contact customer care, it redirects to /app/contact

Comment: @daveoncode, id keep changing. so I cant get from id.

Comment: What if you use `//*[@id="SubmitFormError"]/p/a`?

Comment: @SWiggels, I tried it didn't work either.
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='SubmitFormError']/p/a"));
   System.out.println(text.getText());

Maybe I shouldn't try  getText(), is there any other way I can print this error message?

Comment: If the nested id is changing and provided that the nodes in the dom are always the same, I think you can access the second `p` node (the one which contains the text) in this way (or something like that, I'm not an expert in xpath): "//div[@id='SubmitFormError']"/p[2]... but I fear that you will get only "Your request has not been successful. You need to"

Comment: XPath is not the issue, everytime XPath is showing correct, I think there should be another way to get the error message text.

Comment: Any other suggestion?? I tried all you guys suggested me.

Comment: @niharikagaur, I think you should look at my answer because it is better. `//div[@id='SubmitFormError']/p[2]/a` work only if data is in P N°2, while if `//div[@id='SubmitFormError']//a` find all positions (Caution if you have more one a). I had a click to this link in my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I just made a project from scratch with all the information you provided. It seems to work if you do the following (where the `index.html` is the html-snipped you provided above). Please adjust the `setupPage()` to your needs:

```
public class MyTest extends Selenide {

    @Rule
    public ScreenShooter makeScreenshotOnFailure = ScreenShooter.failedTests();
    private static WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setupPage() {
        Configuration.reportsFolder = "build/reports/integrationTest/screenshots";
        Configuration.browser = WebDriverRunner.PHANTOMJS;
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability(PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "assets/driver/phantomjs_mac");
        String[] phantomJsArgs = { "--ignore-ssl-errors=true" };
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS, phantomJsArgs);
        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        webDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280, 800));
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);
        open("file:///Users/UserName/Desktop/index.html");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        WebElement text = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SubmitFormError']/p[2]/a"));

        System.out.println(text.getText());

    }
}
```

In my case it correctly prints: `contact Customer Care`.

You can now call `text.click();` And you will follow the link to `/app/contact` where you can read new `Elements` and do stuff. I would rename `text` to something more meaningful.

Btw: I took the /p[2] from daveoncode' comment.

In case this is your only test in this class please remember to quit the driver by adding `webDriver.quit();` at the end of your test.

Comment: It worked, thanks.
How should I use text.click() in my code?
thanks for your suggestion on renaming text in some meaningful way too.

Comment: you can add `text.click();` in your testMethod and then try to find (query) a new element on the new page the way you looked for the errorText.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste your html code in a local file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="SubmitFormError" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <p></p>
            <p id="yui_3_17_2_1_1523943995346_146">Your request has not been successful. You need to
 <a href="/app/contact" class="link-dark-bold" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1523943995346_145">contact Customer Care</a> to arrange a replacement.
            </p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And run this test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final OperatingSystem currentOperatingSystem = OperatingSystem.getCurrentOperatingSystem();
    String pathWebdriver = String.format("src/test/resources/drivers/%s/googlechrome/%s/chromedriver%s", currentOperatingSystem.getOperatingSystemDir(),
            SystemArchitecture.getCurrentSystemArchitecture().getSystemArchitectureName(), currentOperatingSystem.getSuffixBinary());
    if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
        logger.error("ERROR when change setExecutable on " + pathWebdriver);
    }
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathWebdriver);
    final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/index.html");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SubmitFormError']//a"));
    logger.info(element.getText());
    element.click();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Log console:

```
contact Customer Care
```

*Note:* 
**If you do Web Interface tests with Java + Selenium, I advise you to use the [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io) framework**